# Break repeating-key XOR, cryptopals set 1 , challenge 6

Tags: python, cryptography, xor

I am working on the Cryptopal challenge "Break repeating-key XOR"  
 https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6 
Relevant textfile is here
 https://cryptopals.com/static/challenge-data/6.txt 
.
**I am having trouble getting the correct "keysize"** (items 3 and 4), my hamming distance functions works as they describe.  I tried several different methods of averaging etc.. but keep getting the result of 20 (answer is 29).
  If you have a suggestion about fixing errors in my code (Python 3.7.6) I would greatly appreciate your advice. Thanks in advance.

#Hamming distance function, this returns 37 for the test phrases below, per the challenge

```
 import pandas as pd
    t1 = "this is a test"
    t2 = "wokka wokka!!!"
    def hamm (s1, s2):
        total = 0
        for a,b in zip(s1,s2):
        tot += (bin(ord(a)^ord(b)).count('1'))
        return(total)
    
with open(r'6.txt') as f:
    text = f.read().replace('\n', '')
```

#create dataframe to store results  
#also iteratively remove recently compared chunks, so next iteration begins with fresh sample 
#continue appending the normalized hamming distances with keysize until all blocks of text processed

```
summary = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['keysize', 'score'])
for key in range(2,41):
    test1 = text 
    while len(test1) >= (2*keysize): 
        x = test1[:keysize]
        y = test1[keysize:(2*keysize)]
        # take the hamming distance and normalize by keysize
        score = hamm(x,y)/keysize
        summary = summary.append({'keysize':keysize,'score':score}, ignore_index=True )  
        test1 = test1[(2*keysize):]
```

#group scores by keysize, take average, find lowest scores keysize

```
summary_final = summary.groupby('keysize')['score'].mean()
keyspace_final = summary_final.idxmin().astype(int)
print('this is the final keyspace: ', keyspace_final) '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I missed the initial step, the file was in base64, and needed to be converted to bytes first, and my hamming function no longer needed to convert the text to bytes.

```
import base64
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    text = base64.b64decode(f.read())

def hamm (s1, s2):
    tot = 0
    for a,b in zip(s1,s2):
        tot += (bin(a^b).count('1'))
    #print('test Hamming distance is: ', tot)
    return(tot)
```